# arranging columns and sub-columns in ggplot2 using facet_wrap?

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap, facet-grid

I would like to know how can I group plots like the following `ggplot` (edited in paint): [Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TifZa.png)

It looks like `facet_wrap()` and `facet_grid()` functions cannot be used to arrange the columns and sub-columns.

Is there any R package that I can use?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe you can take something from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40732543/seeking-workaround-for-gtable-add-grob-code-broken-by-ggplot-2-2-0/40986592#40986592) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39801041/ggplot2-have-common-facet-bar-in-outer-facet-panel-in-3-way-plot/41094539#41094539).

Comment: Thanks@SandyMuspratt for the links! This means there is no direct way to do it using facet_wrap or facet_grid.

Comment: That's correct. The closest you'll get is Jack Brookes' answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can multiply the factors used for columns and subcolumns.

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(disp, mpg)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  facet_wrap(~ cyl * gear, labeller = label_both)
```

[image]

The `labeller` `label_both` here also is useful as it adds the variable name before the value in the facet header.

Comment: Thanks @Jack Brookes for the suggestion! In the top row, is it possible to write cyl:4 only once? Right now it's written 3 times, across three columns. In my Plot, there are two columns of Medial and Final under Pair1. Can I do something similar using the facet_wrap () or facet_grid()?

Comment: Unfortunately not, I imagine the way ggplot2 is coded means facets exist in this grid, and elements can't span between them. Of course, you can always do this manually, but it would require some work

Comment: I came across with GGally package but it requires manipulation of the data.

Comment: You can always read their source code and see how they did it. There's this also https://stackoverflow.com/q/40316169/5024009