# group header labels of facets in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-grid

This code generates the plot below:

```
data(mpg)
mg <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = wt)) + geom_point()
mg + facet_grid(vs + am ~ gear, margins = "vs")
```

[image]

The outer headers of y axis (e.g. 0,0) are the same but in different facets (grey rectangles).
How can I display them as one single rectangle?
I saw a similar [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11353287/how-do-you-add-a-general-label-to-facets-in-ggplot2/12660057#12660057), but it added a label for the entire axis.
Thanks

Comment: Like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/59555102/786542?

Comment: that's perfect, thank you! I can accept it if you move it to answers!

Comment: Ok I can mark it as duplicate